# Angular environment don't loaded

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

I have three environment whit this properties

```
environment.ts
HASVIDEOCALL: {
    VIDEOCALLURL: 'https://trial.herokuapp.com'
  },
environment.prod.ts
HASVIDEOCALL: {
    VIDEOCALLURL: 'https://trial.herokuapp.com'
  },
environment.costumer.ts
HASVIDEOCALL: false
```

in angular.json I have

```
    "costumer": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.hasis.ts"
        },
```

And use this variable in some service like opentok.service.ts with this:

```
  getSessionConfig(room) {
    if (environment.HASVIDEOCALL) {
      let url = environment.HASVIDEOCALL.VIDEOCALLURL + '/room/' + room;
      return this.http.get(url);
    }
  }
```

And now I try to start this enviroment with this:

```
ng serve --configuration=costumer
```

but the Terminal says:

> src/app/services/opentok.service.ts(21,42): error TS2339: Property
>   'VIDEOCALLURL' does not exist on type 'true'.
>
> i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

But as you can see, the type its not true.

An still more extrange it's if I modify any file, only with a console.log, when I save it, automatically rebuild the app and it's works without problems.

Do you know how it happens?

Answer (score 2):

environment.costumer.ts: `HASVIDEOCALL: false`

In the "truthy" case here, I believe the type checking is checking if it's possible to access `VIDEOCALLURL` from the `true` value (instead of your hard coded `false`).

Comment: Thanks @OneLunch Man... Maybe it's true, but do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: You may have to add a type check on the value in the if. `if (environment.HASVIDEOCALL && typeof environment.HASVIDEOCALL === 'object') {`

Answer (score 1):

With the inspiration of @OneLunch Man I solve it

I replace this:

```
if (environment.HASVIDEOCALL) {
```

with this:

```
let hasVideoCall: any = environment.HASVIDEOCALL;
if (hasVideoCall) {
```

Hope it helps someone.